# A "tamper data" for all packages?

Tags: tampering

TamperData is an add-on for firefox, I want to use it for all packages. Is there something like that to modify all requests from all applications on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) as a debugging proxy, and it also claims to be able to edit requests in flight, though I have not done that.